# Freeze notification on hover and continue on mouse leave

Tags: jquery, notifications, setinterval

I am trying to create fake random notifications on my website. I want notification to appear in random time interval from 8.5 - 15 seconds range and disappear in 4 seconds if not closed instantly with X button and not hovered. On hover I want to stop (clear) this interval and function in it. My code seems to have no errors but it does not works. Notifications appear, but X button and hovering stop does not works. I have 2 variations of code and both do not works:

```
 var notify = $("#notify");
 var notification;
 var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (15000 - 8500)) + 8500;

 notify.mouseenter(function() {
  if (notification) { clearInterval(notification) }
 })
 .mouseleave(function() {
     notification = setInterval(function() {
      $.get("http://mywebsite.com/ajaxurl", function(data) {
        notify.fadeIn().html(data).delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
        var noticlose = $('.noticlose');
        noticlose.click(function() {
          notify.fadeOut('slow')
        });
      });
      }, rand);
 }).mouseleave();
```

second:

```
var notify = $("#notify");
var notification;
var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (15000 - 8500)) + 8500;

notification = function() {
      $.get("http://mywebsite.com/ajaxurl", function(data) {
        notify.fadeIn().html(data).delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
        var noticlose = $('.noticlose');
        noticlose.click(function() {
          notify.fadeOut('slow')
        });
      });  
}

var interval = setInterval(notification , rand);

notify.hover(function (ev) {
    clearInterval(interval);
}, function (ev) {
    interval = setInterval(notification , rand);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things you do wrong and thus it does not work.

**First of all** you bind `click` event to `.noticlose` inside interval function which you should not do. So just take this

```js
var noticlose = $('.noticlose');
noticlose.click(function() {
  notify.fadeOut('slow')
});
```

outside your `notification` function.

**Secondly** you stop interval on `mouseenter` and set it again on `mouseleave` and it works properly. But notification will hide because function in interval shows it and hides it. So even if you stop the interval, the function that was triggered earlier will hide the notification. I hope you understand what I'm saying.

So to solve this problem you can use [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) function on `#notify` so that it won't hide.

**Here is an working example** (I removed ajax for it to work, but it should be the same)

```js
var notify = $("#notify");
var notification;
var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (15000 - 8500)) + 8500;

var noticlose = $('.noticlose');
noticlose.click(function() {
  notify.fadeOut('slow')
});

notification = function() {
  notify.fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
}

var interval = setInterval(notification, rand);

notify.on('mouseenter', function(ev) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  notify.stop(true, true);
}).on('mouseleave', function(ev) {
  interval = setInterval(notification, rand);
  notify.delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

```css
#notify {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #CCC;
  display: inline-block;
}

#notify .noticlose {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 15px;
}

#notify .noticlose:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notify">Notify content <span class="noticlose">x</span></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! but I see some issues. First is that close button is coming from ajax, we must define it inside ajax call. I fixed that. The second is that when user leaves notification hover, we want to start 4 seconds timeout fade-out again before setinterval will run again.

Comment: @AkakiKhujadze ok, you did not describe it as such,but sure it is not a problem (already fixed that). As to close button - no, you do not have to define it inside ajax. Since you know its class name you just refer to it by class.

Comment: I already tried what you suggested but it does not works as you stop fadeout animation on hover. Also on mouse leave interval starts to work which includes fadeout with 4 seconds delay. We should completely end the current animation instead of stop on hover and start fadeout with 4 seconds delay again before setinterval starts to work on mouse leave. I can not think how can I do that with jQuery.

Comment: It is being completely ended. You clear the interval therfore when mouse is over it won't hide, and the stop is only for this one hide that was already triggered by interval. As to fadeout on mouseleave I honestly have no idea why do you think this is not a good solution.

Comment: Just keep hovering the notification. It will have overall 4 seconds to hide out. For example hover for 2 seconds and then when you hover again it will have 2 seconds to hide. We want to reset fadout animation every time you  unhover the notification, so to have 4 seconds animation. If there would be something like .reset() instead of .stop(), that would be nice